# Is colour a purely quantum effect?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics

If the colour of an object is determined by the wave-lengths of light that is absorbs and reflects (?) then can colour be described as a purely quantum effect (i.e. without quantum effects an objects might abosrb all light up to a certain wavelength) or is it more prosaic than that?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can get colours due to purely classical interference, [for example in soap films](http://soapbubble.wikia.com/wiki/Color_and_Film_Thickness):

[image: Soap film]

(image is from the article linked above).

However the absorption of light is a quantum process, or at least I cannot think of any examples that are not. So if you are generating colour by absorption of light then yes it is a quantum process.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I thought things that refract light (prisms, oil films, etc.) might be different. The thing that I'm struggling to understand is why simple colour wasn't the inspiration for the discovery quantum theory then, rather than more esoteric effects, like the ultra-violet catastrophe?

Comment: @RobBane explaining the colors you see around you on a day to day basis with quantum mechanics is very much a non-trivial task: you need lots of QM and lots of math. Working *that* problem backwards to intuit the underlying rule is prohibitively difficult. Working spectra backwards is how the detail of QM *was* discovered, but a sufficient set of detailed spectra weren't known until quite some time after the basics of classical optics was well developed.

Comment: If my underlying assumption had been correct (i.e. that absorbtion of light at discreet wavelengths gives us the ability to perceive their colour rather than classical reflection) then it would seem inituitive that a quantum type effect was at play - e.g. we shouldn't ever see red objects as all of the wavelengths below that eneergy level should also be absorbed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different tack.  Yes, detection of photons in the retina is quantum.  No, color perception is not.  Our brain does strange things with the relative signal levels coming off the various rods and cones, and reports the perceived colors based on some processing.

The reason I'm suggesting that color perception itself is not quantum, among other things, is that there are many colors which we perceive only as the combination of 2 or more quantum-detected wavelengths.  If you look at a [chromaticity diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CIE1931xy_blank.svg), (quoting from the wikipedia page),

> The diagram represents all of the chromaticities visible to the
>   average person. These are shown in color and this region is called the
>   gamut of human vision. The gamut of all visible chromaticities on the
>   CIE plot is the tongue-shaped or horseshoe-shaped figure shown in
>   color. The curved edge of the gamut is called the spectral locus and
>   corresponds to monochromatic light (each point representing a pure hue
>   of a single wavelength), with wavelengths listed in nanometers. The
>   straight edge on the lower part of the gamut is called the line of
>   purples. These colors, although they are on the border of the gamut,
>   have no counterpart in monochromatic light. Less saturated colors
>   appear in the interior of the figure with white at the center.

Comment: I think I'm with you on the colour-percepetion 'angle'. However, am I right in assuming that the objects absorb different wavelengths of light which enables us to perceive their colour, and that effect is a quantum one?

Comment: @RobBane well, strictly speaking, it's only the reflected wavelengths which define the object's color.  What wavelengths are absorbed (hence not reflected) is a matter both of quantum effects, i.e. direct photon absorption, and physical form, such as surface roughness and 'light traps' which enhance the probability of absorption due to the number of times a reflected photon hits a surface.

Comment: Ah, I see, the objects themselves don't aborb light in an quantum manner, they reflect the wavelengths in a different manner - a la classical theory, rather than absorb them. I think I was assuming that because black (as well as non-shiny) object tend to get hotter than white (and shiny) objects in the sun, that colour was all about absorbtion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith a few notes you might find helpful:

Physicists talk about two kinds of fields: classical fields and quantum fields. Actually, *we believe that all fields in nature are quantum fields.* A classical field is just a special large-scale manifestation of a quantum field. (My emphasis.)

~Dyson

If you ask a physicist what is his idea of yellow light, he will tell you that it is transversal electromagnetic waves of wavelength in the neighborhood of 590 millimicrons. If you ask him: But where does yellow come in? he will say: In my picture not at all, but these kinds of vibrations, when they hit the retina of a healthy eye, give the person whose eye it is the sensation of yellow.

~Schrödinger

Thus the colors with their various qualities and intensities fulfill  the axioms of vector geometry if addition is interpreted as mixing; consequently, projective geometry applies to the color qualities.

~Weyl

It is just like the mathematics of the addition of vectors, where (a, b, c) are the components of one vector, and (a', b', c') are those of another vector, and the new light Z is then the "sum" of the vectors. This subject has always appealed to physicists and mathematicians. In fact, Schrödinger wrote a wonderful paper on color vision in which he developed this theory of vector analysis as applied to the mixing of colors.

~Feynman

The mathematical machinery of QM became that of spectral analysis.

~Steen

I have concentrated on examples from physics since they can be described independently of mathematics. These examples can also be formulated in precise mathematical terms. In this way, they become part of harmonic analysis in mathematics, interpreted in the broad sense above. The general duality between geometric objects and spectral objects permeates mathematics. It has a pervasive influence in such diverse areas as group theory, topology, differential geometry, number theory and algebraic geometry, as well as the areas of analysis and differential equations with which it is more traditionally associated.

~Arthur